How to send NFT from my current wallet to another using solana wallet adapter?
Did some digging and found this piece of code, but it is not working anymore. Please help
const mintToken = new PublicKey(''); // 4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU is USDC token address on solana devnet
      const recipientAddress = new PublicKey('');

      const transactionInstructions: TransactionInstruction[] = [];
      const associatedTokenFrom = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mintToken, publicKey);
      const fromAccount = await getAccount(connection, associatedTokenFrom);
      const associatedTokenTo = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mintToken, recipientAddress);
      if (!(await connection.getAccountInfo(associatedTokenTo))) {
        transactionInstructions.push(
          createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
            publicKey,
            associatedTokenTo,
            recipientAddress,
            mintToken
          )
        );
      }
      transactionInstructions.push(
        createTransferInstruction(
          fromAccount.address, // source
          associatedTokenTo, // dest
          publicKey,
          1000000 // transfer 1 USDC, USDC on solana devnet has 6 decimal
        )
      );
      const transaction = new Transaction().add(...transactionInstructions);
      const signature = await configureAndSendCurrentTransaction(
        transaction,
        connection,
        publicKey,
        signTransaction
      );


The source should also be a token account update the transfer instruction with
// --- snip 

 transactionInstructions.push(
        createTransferInstruction(
          getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(mintToken, publicKey), // source
          associatedTokenTo, // dest
          publicKey,
          1000000 // transfer 1 USDC, USDC on solana devnet has 6 decimal
        )
      );


Thank you so much. It worked. You are a life saver. I've been searching non-stop for 2 days. Can you explain more about the getAssociatedTokenAddressSync function?
